# How to save Python coding in Command Prompt as a file?

Tags: python, file, save, command-prompt, python-3.4

I just typed an example from a book in Python34 of a running Command Prompt.

but now I want to save this python program as file for future uses. Since I have never used Command Prompt before and I also searched online but most of them cannot answer.

Can anyone show the solution here? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean save it in a .py file?

Comment: The IPython shell is a very comfortable environment for such kind of experiments, see http://ipython.org/.

Answer (score 6):

You can save lines in ipython using [%save](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-save):

**Usage:**

> %save [options] filename n1-n2 n3-n4 ... n5 .. n6 ...
>   Options:
>
> -r: use ‘raw’ input. By default, the ‘processed’ history is used, so that magics are loaded in their transformed version to valid Python. If this option is given, the raw input as typed as the command line is used instead.
>
> -f: force overwrite. If file exists, %save will prompt for overwrite unless -f is given.
>
> -a: append to the file instead of overwriting it.
>
> This function uses the same syntax as %history for input ranges, then saves the lines to the filename you specify.
>
> It adds a ‘.py’ extension to the file if you don’t do so yourself, and it asks for confirmation before overwriting existing files.
>
> If -r option is used, the default extension is .ipy.

```
In [1]: def foo():
   ...:     print("hello world")
   ...:     

In [2]: %save my_code 1
The following commands were written to file `my_code.py`:
def foo():
    print("hello world")


In [3]: cat my_code.py
# coding: utf-8
def foo():
    print("hello world")
```

Comment: I get nothing but SyntaxError from following this method.

Answer (score -1):

write the code in a text editor and save it. then "cd" to the folder your file is in and type "python [filename].py"

```
>>> cd C:\Users\me\Desktop
Users\me\Desktop> python myCode.py
```

where i learned this **(watch the whole video before anything! it is only 7 minutes long!)**:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enG7xaK7PfA