# How can I Save a Python Script output to a file when using Command Prompt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-prompt, text-to-speech

I am using a speech-to-text example from Microsoft [example here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/python/console).

After following the steps, we can run the example with this command (in command prompt)

```
python3 main.py
```

And, in the command prompt all the results are showed. Great!

However, I want to save all the results into a file (could be JSON, txt, csv...). I saw on Stackoverflow some other persons with the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30506069/how-to-save-python-coding-in-command-prompt-as-a-file) (however this is not really working in my example), and I knew from a previous project that I could save results to a JSON file (with Scrapy), with a command like this:

```
scrapy crawl Script -o name_json_file.json
```

**Therefore my question**: Can I - directly save - all the results (that the Command Prompt shows) to a file when using the command prompt? And if not, what is the best (alternative) way to save the outputs in a file?

Many thanks!

Comment: looks like this is your requirement https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21963270/how-to-execute-a-python-script-and-write-output-to-txt-file

Comment: Are you looking for `python3 main.py > your_text_file.txt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is

```
YOUR-COMMAND > c:\PATH\TO\FOLDER\OUTPUT.txt
```

so in your case its

```
python3 main.py > c:\PATH\TO\FOLDER\OUTPUT.txt
```

If you want to save and also view the output you can do

```
python3 main.py > c:\PATH\TO\FOLDER\OUTPUT.txt | type
```

Comment: For completeness: in some situation output might also be written to `stderr`, then you need to use `&>` instead of just `>`.

Comment: Looks good! Especially the last one is interesting for my example. However, I receive a "The syntax is incorrect" when trying  python main.py >output_text.txt | type        are you sure that the syntax is ok? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yeah the syntax is fine ensure you are using the right version of python. In the comment you wrote python main.py but in the question and the instructions it says python3 main.py.

Comment: @Roverflow the space between > and output_text.txt is important